# AS3 URLRequest POST Only Works When Compiled in HTML Wrapper

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, urlrequest

I'm attempting to send a POST request with data to another domain with this code:

```
_snapshot_id = 1369022400;
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://fuzzykittens/radar");
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

//set variables for post
var postVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
postVars.snapshot = String(_snapshot_id);
urlRequest.data = postVars;

//initialize weather proccess request
weatherProcRequest = new URLLoader(urlRequest);

weatherProcRequest.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,
    weatherProcRequest_CompleteHandler);
weatherProcRequest.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,
    weatherProcRequest_ErrorHandler);
weatherProcRequest.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,
    weatherProcRequest_ErrorHandler);

weatherProcRequest.load(urlRequest);
```

When I set the flex compiler to use an HTML wrapper, the request works.  When I don't use a wrapper, the request throws an io error #2032.  I think it's not sending the snapshot id, but I don't know why.

Is there any obvious reason why a request would send data when debugged in an html wrapper and fail to do so when debugged outside an html wrapper?

fuzzykittens has a crossdomain.xml with

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
```

Comment: Being more specific about your environment will probably help (are you using AIR for a desktop or Mobile application or are you just trying to execute a SWF by itself, and if so why?)  There are different security restraints depending on the context of a SWFs execution.

Comment: I'm running the SWF by itself.  The decision to do so was not my own so I don't know why.  When I use the HTML wrapper, it's opened in firefox.  Thanks, this is my first Stack Overflow question.

Comment: This could be when you use URLRequestMethod.POST without the wrapper, try it with URLRequestMethod.GET for testing. You can as well listen to HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS  and HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS on the URLLoader to see the status returned

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.  Adobe very briefly mentions this caveat in URLRequest's livedoc:

> Note: If running in Flash Player and the referenced form has no body, Flash Player automatically uses a GET operation, even if the method is set to URLRequestMethod.POST. For this reason, it is recommended to always include a "dummy" body to ensure that the correct method is used.

When I just ran the SWF without a body, the snapshot id was not sent as a post var so the server responded differently.

It's definitely not the answer I wanted, but it feels good to know what was going on.  Thank you for your comments.